ChatOllama not able to invoke response
I'm trying to test llama3 on my Macbook Air (8gb RAM). I've installed Ollama and it up and running on http://localhost:11434. I'm also able to chat with it via terminal. But I'm not able use it via VS code. It throws the following output and also the error -
Checkpoint 1
Checkpoint 2
checkpoint 3
<class 'list'>
<class 'langchain_core.messages.human.HumanMessage'>
Input to invoke: [HumanMessage(content='Are you ready?', additional_kwargs={}, response_metadata={})]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sandeephugar/VSCProjects/purplekicks/manager/llmtest.py", line 156, in <module>
    response = llm.invoke(test_message)
  File "/Users/sandeephugar/VSCProjects/purplekicks/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_core/language_models/chat_models.py", line 286, in invoke
    self.generate_prompt(
  File "/Users/sandeephugar/VSCProjects/purplekicks/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_core/language_models/chat_models.py", line 786, in generate_prompt
    return self.generate(prompt_messages, stop=stop, callbacks=callbacks, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sandeephugar/VSCProjects/purplekicks/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_core/language_models/chat_models.py", line 643, in generate
    raise e
  File "/Users/sandeephugar/VSCProjects/purplekicks/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_core/language_models/chat_models.py", line 633, in generate
    self._generate_with_cache(
  File "/Users/sandeephugar/VSCProjects/purplekicks/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_core/language_models/chat_models.py", line 851, in _generate_with_cache
    result = self._generate(
  File "/Users/sandeephugar/VSCProjects/purplekicks/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_ollama/chat_models.py", line 644, in _generate
    final_chunk = self._chat_stream_with_aggregation(
  File "/Users/sandeephugar/VSCProjects/purplekicks/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_ollama/chat_models.py", line 558, in _chat_stream_with_aggregation
    tool_calls=_get_tool_calls_from_response(stream_resp),
  File "/Users/sandeephugar/VSCProjects/purplekicks/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_ollama/chat_models.py", line 70, in _get_tool_calls_from_response
    for tc in response["message"]["tool_calls"]:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Here is my code -
from langchain_ollama import ChatOllama
from langchain_core.messages import AIMessage, HumanMessage

# Initialize the LLM (Ollama)
llm = ChatOllama(model="llama3")


print("Checkpoint 1")

# Check if the model is accessible
if not llm:
    raise ValueError("LLM instance is not initialized properly.")

print("Checkpoint 2")

# Test a simple input
test_message = [HumanMessage(content="Are you ready?")]
print("checkpoint 3")
print(type(test_message))  # Should print <class 'list'>
print(type(test_message[0]))
print("Input to invoke:", test_message)

# Invoke the model and get the response
response = llm.invoke(test_message)
print(response.content)


# Check if the response is not None
if response is None:
    raise ValueError("The model did not respond. Ensure the Ollama server is running and the model is loaded.")

print("LLM is ready and responding.")
print("Checkpoint 4")

# Iterate over the response list and print each message content
for msg in response:
    print(msg.content)

print("Checkpoint 6")

I've tried to debug and handle errors, hence the code looks the way it does. I tried taking help from chatgpt, but then it started going in loops. I also tried using -
test_message = [(
    "system",
    "You are a helpful assistant here to chat.",
),
("human", "hello, nice to meet you!"),]

But still the same error.
